# Deploying JS app on Heroku - error status 503

Tags: javascript, heroku

I’ve prepared simple app to test if works on Heroku. Locally seems to works fine, unfortunately on Heroku after some time of loading I receive “Service Unavailable” error. Can someone please advice what is the reason of this error and how to run this app ?

[Heroku local web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uaS5.png)

[Locally works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsCXc.png)

Repo on Git: https://github.com/tomaszchmura/OnHeroku

[Error on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8EWX.png)

Heroku logs:

> 2020-04-19T06:51:16.211281+00:00 app[web.1]: Server On 5000
>   2020-04-19T06:52:13.302269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2020-04-19T09:26:59.045884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=directhero.herokuapp.com request_id=4c36cf02-2713-4ab4-a305-67a0b20eb7c1 fwd="37.30.0.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2020-04-19T09:26:59.663890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=directhero.herokuapp.com request_id=c5a2bd5c-740c-44d9-bb1e-9baefc20b7a7 fwd="37.30.0.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2020-04-19T09:37:12.003882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=directhero.herokuapp.com request_id=65f2621c-94ce-4241-95c5-21eac6533218 fwd="37.30.0.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2020-04-19T09:37:12.353987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=directhero.herokuapp.com request_id=d2afcb89-48a5-4045-a838-af1cb8edd953 fwd="37.30.0.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Can You please advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen on port that Heroku provides you in the environment variable

```js
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

You can access the service on port 80 afterwards!

Comment: Hello, I am presenting this problem, I would like to know if you can see my question where I specify everything, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626009/heroku-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not